# neo4j defining multiple types for relationships

Tags: neo4j

Is there any way to define multiple types for a relationship in a neo4j database?

Does the neo4j development team have any plan to substitute relationship types with labels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this closed neo4j issue, there are no plans to support that: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/1199

Comment: Boo.  This would be a very useful feature for managing relationship taxonomies